# Jquery-ui sortable - hide the original list while dragging hides the dragged item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I use Jquery-UI to do kind of a board. Basicly I have 2 sortable lists, and I take elements from one list to drop it in the other one.

System works well. Now I want to hide the container div of the first list while dragging an element to make the second list more visible.

To make it clear here is a simplified code:

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ['.sortable'],
        helper: "clone",
        start: function (event, ui) {
          $("#list_one").hide()
        }
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="list_one" style="border: 1px solid red">
<ul class="sortable" style="min-height: 100px">
<li id="my_item">my item</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="list_two" style="border: 1px solid blue">
<ul class="sortable" style="min-height: 100px">
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So The drag and drop works well (even when the first div disappears, I still can drop my "invisible" item in the second list.

But it's still a bit problematic to not see my dragged object.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right then, this is what I came up with to fix your issue, the problem was in your code is that you are add attribute display none to `#list_one` using $("#list_one").hide() which in tern hide your dragged element since it inside `#list_one`, to fix this I added a helper function that clone the dragged (not sure why clone helper didn't work) and append it to a different element (in my snippet `<body>`) and once sorting drag stop it will remove the cloned element, here is a working snippet:

```js
$(".sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ['.sortable2'],
    helper: function (e, li) {
        copyHelper = li.clone().appendTo('body');
        return copyHelper;
    },
    stop: function () {
        copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
        $("#list_one").css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
      $("#list_one").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
$(".sortable2").sortable();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="list_one" style="border: 1px solid red">
        <ul class="sortable1" style="min-height: 100px">
            <li id="my_item1">my item</li>
            <li id="my_item2">my item</li>
            <li id="my_item3">my item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="list_two" style="border: 1px solid blue">
        <ul class="sortable2" style="min-height: 100px">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

in another note I would suggest that you don't hide the element just add lower opacity value to it, thats a better UX, here is a working snippet too:

```js
$(".sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ['.sortable2'],
    helper: function (e, li) {
        copyHelper = li.clone().appendTo('body');
        return copyHelper;
    },
    stop: function () {
        copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
        $("#list_one").css('opacity', 1);  
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
      $("#list_one").css('opacity', 0.3);
    }
});
$(".sortable2").sortable();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="list_one" style="border: 1px solid red">
        <ul class="sortable1" style="min-height: 100px">
            <li id="my_item1">my item</li>
            <li id="my_item2">my item</li>
            <li id="my_item3">my item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="list_two" style="border: 1px solid blue">
        <ul class="sortable2" style="min-height: 100px">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I got why it didn't work but I didn't know how to fix it .... And you gave me the answer. Thank you very much.
Yeah for the UX it would be better to play with opacity, but if I want to hide this div it's because there is some of the linked lists below it where I can want to drop this item. So changing the opacity will not give me access to these lists. Anyway thanks again

Comment: Glad to help :)